# Alamofire JSON Encoding boolean issues?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, jsonencoder

Is there any custom encoding to encode Bool as true instead of 0 or 1 ?

URLEncoding has option to change the Bool as literal or numeric. But JSONEncoding.default doesn't have that option.

Is there any one who has created JSONEncoding with respect to this problem ?

Comment: convert it to cfboolean

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `boolEncoding: .literal` in the `URLEncoding` initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert the boolean value using following method, By default return false. It will work for Bool as literal or numeric.

```
func boolean(_ anything: Any?) -> Bool {
    if let any = anything {
        if let num = any as? NSNumber {
            return num.boolValue
        } else if let str = any as? NSString {
            return str.boolValue
        }
    }
    return false
}
```